# Having issues iterating through JSON object in login application

Tags: javascript, html

Basically I'm building a simple login app for JavaScript using an API. I get a 200 ok from the API and in the response I get all the posts, what I'm trying to do is to match the user-input with one of the posts in order to login. Do I have to iterate through everyone? Spontaneously  feel that it would be bad for performance. So how should I proceed in order to make the code in the best way possible? Below is my JavaScript Code and HTML code.

```
async function login() {
    const username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    const users = 'http://webbred2.utb.hb.se/~fewe/api/api.php?data=students';
  
    try {
      const response = await fetch(users, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({ 
          username: username, 
          password: password 
        })
      });
  
      const data = await response.json();

      // Loop through the data to find a match with the user input
      let authenticated = false;  
      for(let user of users){
        if (user.username === username && user.password === password){
            authenticated = true;
        window.location.href = "quiz.html"; 
    }
    else 
    {
        // login failed
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Incorrect username or password";
    }
}
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
      document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "An error occurred";
    }
  }
```

HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="sv" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Login Kursöversikt</title>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="login">
    <h1>Logga in här för kursöversikt!</h1>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"><br><br>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Login" onclick="login()">
  </div>
  <p id="message"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to login in with credentials that a user inputs and match them towards the API-response so I get logged in.

Comment: You have to do the validation on the server, return a response to the client then based on the response you can login the user.

Comment: I see use you are using `===` instead of `==`.

Comment: You're using a dummy API endpoint to get some sample data. Looping over the users in this example data is probably fine for your purposes right now. In a real sever situation, however, authentication endpoints will not return all users' data in a list like this.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought.. its a API set up just for the purpose of this course that we can use so it doesn't really take in consideration safety etc.. since its dummy data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Note

It looks like your server is sending a *PLAINTEXT LIST OF EVERY PASSWORD IN THE SYSTEM*. This is not a good idea. You should do the password checking on the server side so that the user does not get that information sent to them. The best practice would be to also encrypt the passwords so that they are not stored in plain text.

## Answer

But aside from that, one way to do faster lookups is to use an object instead of an array.

With a list of users, you will need to search for the user using a `for` loop or `users.find()`.

```js
const users = [
    {username: 'a', password: 'aa'},
    {username: 'b', password: 'bb'},
    {username: 'c', password: 'cc'},
];
```

With an object, you can go directly to the user you want using `userPasswords[username]`.

```js
const userPasswords = {
    a: 'aa',
    b: 'bb',
    c: 'cc',
};
```

Comment: Yeah the server is set up as a dummy, since its just made for purposes of a JavaScript course I'm doing

Comment: Don't understand though why I get Incorrect password or username when I try to run my application :(

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought the code worked and you were just asking about performance. I now see that in the code you posted you are looping over the URL of the API endpoint instead of looping over the actual users. `users` is a string and `data` is the response data, which you don't actually use.

Comment: Ah dude.... it wasn't only that the API setup had also the "login" as main attribute, but I did the changes you suggested and it now works! :) Thank you man